# Can't install driver for AL500AC on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, drivers

I'm trying to install a wi-fi driver for my wi-fi dongle on Ubuntu. The guide says I should:

- extract the folder (done)
- then type `sudo make`(done)
- then type `sudo apt-get install build-essential`(done)
- and last type `sudo modprobe 8812au`.

Now this is where it stops, when I press enter I get the message:

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module 8812au not found.
```

The folder looks like this: 
[image: folder]

EDIT: The tutorial used was this one: http://www.linux.com/learn/answers/view/1664-how-do-i-install-the-driver-for-jensen-airlink-500ac-in-ubuntu-1404-lts

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Would you please clarify which 'guide' you used? (link in question please).

Comment: Done, haven't been on stack exchange in a long time :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the steps should be:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential git
git clone https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au.git
cd rtl8812au
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 8812au
```

If you encounter errors, please post them; warnings are probably alright.

Comment: Hey. I still get the same error. You said you knew of a newer version? Care to share?

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: Confirmed. This worked for me as well. THANK YOU!

Comment: Hey, I can run these commands (from 'make' and down), but when I restart my computer, I have to do it again. Know any workaround?

Comment: @FredrikA. Does it work if you simply do: sudo modprobe 8812au?

Comment: chili555; Hey, it turns out something was wrong with my distro, and I'm now using Elementary OS Beta 2, and it works perfectly! Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

I found an up to date version of this driver (version-4.3.14) that is configured to work well on newer Debian and RaspberryPi kernels.

This has been tested by me on 16.04 with kernel 4.2.0-23.

First, install some dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-5 build-essential git linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Then, run the following commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/diederikdehaas/rtl8812AU.git
cd rtl8812AU
make CC=/usr/bin/gcc-5
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 8812au
echo 8812au | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
```

[source / more info](https://github.com/diederikdehaas/rtl8812AU)

Comment: Sounds great! Will try to install tomorrow :)

Comment: @mchid : I was trying your suggestions in a CentOS system: The code does not compile: include/net/cfg80211.h:4562: note: expected ‘struct wireless_dev *’ but argument is of type ‘_nic_hdl’
/home/Manuel/8812/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/core/rtw_p2p.c:3539: error: too many arguments to function ‘cfg80211_remain_on_channel_expired’
I will try to force compilation but this is a bad sign. Thanks.

Comment: @HermanJaramillo Cent OS question belong on http://unix.stackexchange.com/. You can use your existing stackexchange profile to sign in and it will add your profile to http://unix.stackexchange.com/. I don't know much about Cent but might be able to help you out.